# Splitting a sentence using Colon (:) and Break (<br>)

Tags: php, regex

**Input**

```
<?php
$input = 'After <span style="color:green;">10</span> years : XYZ 38.38 <br><span style="font-size:11px;"><strong>AB212</strong> is applicable on 2025</span>';
?>
```

**Expected Output - After split, store strings in a single array, say $Output**

```
 $Output[0] = 'After <span style="color:green;">10</span> years';
 $Output[1] = 'XYZ 38.38';
 $Output[2] = '<span style="font-size:11px;"><strong>AB212</strong> is applicable on 2025</span>';
```

**Task**

> Split the sentence using Colon `:` and Break `<br>`. I got so many options from stackoverflow search and I successfully did it using `explode` and `preg_split`.
>
> I want to simplify the program using a single builtin function, I was trying `preg_split`

**My Tries**

```
<?php
# separate by :
$output1_Array    = explode(' : ', ($input));
$output1_Array[0] = isset($output1_Array[0]) ? $output1_Array[0] : '';
$output1_Array[1] = isset($output1_Array[1]) ? $output1_Array[1] : '';

# separate by <br>
//$output2_Array = explode("<br />", $output1_Array[1]);
//$output2_Array = preg_split("/[<br>]+/", $output1_Array[1]);
//$output2_Array = preg_split('/\s?<br>\s?/', $output1_Array[1], NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$output2_Array   = preg_split('/<br[^>]*>/i', $output1_Array[1]);
$output2_Array[0] = isset($output2_Array[0]) ? $output2_Array[0] : '';
$output2_Array[1] = isset($output2_Array[1]) ? $output2_Array[1] : '';

print_r('1:'.$output1_Array[0]);
print_r('2:'.$output2_Array[0]);
print_r('3:'.$output2_Array[1]);
?>
```

Comment: your expected output have php code???

Comment: do you really need the the tags?

Comment: what variables do you want to extract from the input?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @yivi mentioned already in "My Tries"

Comment: @mwweb Colon and Break tag, already in the question heading and content

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte expected output: The strings split by colon and break tag

Comment: @yivi Oh!! I understand the question mistake and edited

Comment: $Output = preg_split('/:|<br>?/', $input);    https://regex101.com/r/5EWkbR/1

Answer (score 0):

To split your string by colons surrounded by one space and `<br>` tags *possibly* surrounded by one space, you can use the following expression:

`/\s:\s|\s?<br>\s?/g`

In this expression, there is the `|` character that indicates to match the left and the right side of it (i.e. `\s:\s` and `\s?<br>\s?`) in your string. Technically, it acts as a logical `OR`.
Note the usage of the global modifier at the end of the regex.

You can get more info on [this demo page](https://regex101.com/r/avEY1B/1).

With your code, it would be:

```
$output = preg_split('/\s:\s|\s?<br>\s?/g', $input)
```

The `$output` array will contain those strings that you can use as you want:

```
After <span style="color:green;">10</span> years
XYZ 38.38
<span style="font-size:11px;"><strong>AB212</strong> is applicable on 2025</span>
```